# Unable to Read a large CSV into Panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I cant read the whole file into a dataframe so I tried breaking it into very small chunks

```py
for chunk in pd.read_csv(r'HugeFile.txt',chunksize=1000, sep=r"\s+", header=None):
    df = pd.concat(chunk)
print(df)
```

But I am still getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data Science\Python\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    pd.read_csv(r'HugeFile.txt',chunksize=1000, sep=r"\s+", header=None):
  File "C:\Data Science\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1034, in __next__
    return self.get_chunk()
  File "C:\Data Science\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1084, in get_chunk
    return self.read(nrows=size)
  File "C:\Data Science\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1057, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Data Science\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2061, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 756, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 783, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 827, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 814, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1951, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 8, saw 4
```

Thanks

Comment: Does line 8 of the csv have 4 fields instead of 3? does every other row have 3 fields? or do the first 7 rows have 3 but really should have 4 (and so the 4th is null), and then row 8 actually has 4 fields?

Comment: I'd try using `nrows = 100` in your call to read_csv() and see if it still has issues. If there are still issues, you may need to look at your data and figure out if there is some weird characters. For example you might have a text column that happens to have a comma in it?

Comment: This file is a very badly formated file. I am trying to learn to clean this kind of data. Line 8 has 4 fields instead of 3 as you said but the fact that I used sep=r"\s+" shouldn't that make every field seperated by space into a column in the df ? Thanks

Comment: @user3234112, yes, that is how that separated should work. not knowing what the sheet looks like, though, i can't say much about if it is working as expected or where that issue is.

i think you may need to work on cleaning up the data prior to making a dataframe out of it...